# How to do a like button script?

Tags: php

I am making a social networking site but I can't figure out how I would do the like button to where it would submit into the database for the correct status it's liking without a page refresh or a form reset happening which overall just destroys the script anyway and I can't use an external script because it will not be able to have the status id which is returned with $row['id']; P.S. I'm using PHP.  But it has to be in the while() loop that gets the statuses from the database.  Ask any questions necessary to help me.

This is an edited version of the code to make it less bulky but if you need the full thing just let me know and I'll paste it.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_feed))
{
    echo "<div class='container' style='background-color:blue;' margin:0px; padding:0px;'>";
    echo "<h1 class='header-text' style='font-size:300%;'>@<u>" . $row['username'] . "</u></h1><h1 style='float:right; padding:0px; margin:0px; margin-right:5px;'>" . $row['id'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<center>";
    echo "<h3 style='font-size:250%; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>" . $row['status'] . "</h3>";
    echo "<h3 style='font-size:200% padding:0px; margin:0px;'>" . $row['time'] . "</h3>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "</center>";
    echo "</div>";  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: _Please don't badger me with rules_ We would be most willing to help if only we understood exectly what the question was. There are some real experts that haunt this site! But, if you cannot be bothered to ask an answerable question, they wont bother trying to winkle out your real question. Be more specific. Add some example code. Or you will not get any help as we dont know how to help. **Nobody here is clairvoyant**

Comment: Sorry, it seemed like you were trying to get me to read rules and force me ask something a certain way.  I would be more then happy to give you example code.  But please if you need something just ask instead of redirecting me to question guidelines.  The next comment will have the code I'm trying to use it with.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  This is an edited version of the code to make it less bulky but if you need the full thing just let me know and I'll paste it.  http://pastebin.com/vtGdxjCa

Comment: Ok so here we go again, please edit your question when adding extra information to your question. Links are not encouraged as they are not guaranteed to exist in a month when someone else looks at your question trying to find a solution to a similiar problem.

Comment: I still dont know what you want. The code you show does not look like it is on a `<form>` and there is no indication of javascript and AJAX mechanisms. We have no idea what your database looks like, so please read your question. **Could you give an answer to what you have actually put in it?**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry.  What I'm asking isn't necessarily for source code support, but what do you think would be the best way to add a like status option.  I can handle forms and things, but how do I get the ID and make it like the correct status instead of it liking all of the statuses or some other bug like that.

Comment: Use the ID of the correct status

Answer (score 0):

Use "onclick"

```
<script>
    function click01()
      {
          <--What to do -->
      }
</script>

//change input type to button
<input type = "button" onlick = "click01"/>
```

Comment: I have to detect it with PHP so I can get the $row['id'] and make a new mysql query.  I can't use client-side.  Also to detect the button click I'm using if(isset($_POST['button'])) {}